# Javascript - HAPPY.js password

Tags: javascript, jquery, happy.js

i'm using happy.js to validate a form. for this form, i need the user to submit one of five possible passwords, if the user doesn't submit any of the passwords correctly the form has to fail.

not sure what i'm doing wrong here. appreciate any help. code below:

FRONT:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
                        $('#form10').isHappy({
                            fields: {
                                // reference the field you're talking about, probably by `id`
                                // but you could certainly do $('[name=name]') as well.

                                 '#Field226': {
                                     required: true,
                                     message: 'Please submit a valid Activation Code.',
                                     test: happy.activationCode
                                 }
                            }
                        });

                    });
    </script>
```

HAPPY METHOD

```
var happy = {
    activationCode: function (val) {
        return (val == "dfgdfsg" || "uyioiuo" || "bvnm" || "zxvcx" || "z453v");
    }

};
```

Comment: You realize this is not secure right....

Comment: `val == "dfgdfsg" || "uyioiuo" || "bvnm" || "zxvcx" || "z453v"` does not do what you think it does. Repeat `val ==` or iterate over an array instead.

Comment: So when I click "view source" on your web page I get free activation codes? Nice! On an unrelated note, what is it I'm going to be stea-- err buying from you once your done?

Comment: hate to put a kabash on that, i'm going to be echoing all this out in php.

Comment: if you echo all of that out in php...it's still gonna be in the page source

Comment: meant php tags, but you're right that's not going to work either. i'll have to find some other way of hiding those tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will fix your problem...

```
return (val == "dfgdfsg" || val == "uyioiuo" || val == "bvnm" ||
    val == "zxvcx" || val == "z453v");
```

You need to do the comparison of `val == "something"` for each of the values, which you weren't doing.

But I **strongly** urge you to reconsider this.  Anyone can view your page source and will see all 5 passwords.

Comment: yep. i'll be sure to cover my tracks.

Answer (score 0):

Your test function will always evaluate to true:

```
return (val == "dfgdfsg" || "uyioiuo" || "bvnm" || "zxvcx" || "z453v");
```

Because, you're doing OR with a string, and strings are truthy.
You need to change it to this:

```
return (
    val == "dfgdfsg" || 
    val == "uyioiuo" || 
    val == "bvnm"    || 
    val == "zxvcx"   || 
    val == "z453v");
```

Of course, as others pointed out, this is completely insecure, so I hope you're just testing it and will have a more secure way of checking for passwords.